# Отладка C# без Visual Studio

Tags: c#

Чем можно отладить приложение C# .Net, без использования Visual Studio. В чем проблема, удаленная ОС на которая стоит приложение виртуальная, скорость работы ужасающая, использовать remote debug невозможно так порты для него закрыты. Может есть что то легковесное что может пройти по Source Code. .pdb и src в наличии.

Comment: А если использовать VPN?

Comment: Да это возможно, но хотелось бы избежать этого. Может есть какие-то тулы.

Comment: Либо как вариант поднять локальную виртуалку с более мощными ресурсами, заодно и порты открыты будут.